# Failed to load Typescript interpreter: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'

Tags: node.js, typescript, pm2

I have a nodejs api deployed using pm2. However when its deployed i get the following error:

```
Failed to load Typescript interpreter: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'
Require stack:
 - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js

Server Running On: 0.0.0.0:8080
```

**ecosystem.config.ts**

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "api",
            script: "src/server.ts",
            instances: "1",
            exec_mode: "cluster",
            interpreter: "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node",
            interpreter_args: "--require ts-node/register/transpile-only --require tsconfig-paths/register",
            merge_logs: true,
            max_restarts: 10,
        },
    ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.14.1",
        "typescript": "^4.6.3"
    },
```

Any ideas why i receive this error message?

Answer (score 0):

You have got `ts-node` as a dev dependency, which won't be available in production builds. If you would be using the module in production, install it as a normal dependency.

`npm install --save ts-node`

Comment: hmm interesting, i wonder how the server is able to run without ts-node if thats the case?

Comment: I jsut tested this and installed it as a regular production depedency, i still get the error

Comment: Just realized that it's PM2 that's complaining about ts-node. Could you please try installing ts-node globally and see if that fixes.

`npm install -g ts-node`